# Can't pass a list as class attribute

Tags: python, oop

I have created an iterator. I'm trying to iterate through recipe ingredients, to check if a vegan person can it it, or not.

```
class Vegan:

    NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT = ['egg', 'milk', 'honey', 'butter']

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.ingredient_list = (args)
        self.index = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == len(self.ingredient_list):
            raise StopIteration
        for ingredient in self.ingredient_list:
            if ingredient in Vegan.NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT:
                self.index += 1
                return ('{} is a vegan ingredient'.format(ingredient[self.index]))
            else:
                self.index += 1
                return ('{} is NOT a vegan ingredient'.format(ingredient[self.index]))

iterable = Vegan('tomato', 'banana', 'asd', 'egg', 'tomato')
iterator = iter(iterable)
while True:
    try:
        print(next(iterator))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

as you can see, I'm passing *args, which should be a list, but whenever I try to run this, it iterates through the first word, and checks the letters of the word 'tomato'. I want my iterator to go through the ingredients, and if something is not in the NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT list, then print as it is in the code. How can I pass in a list?

Comment: Isn't a simple `for v in Vegan(..):print(v)` equivalent to your last lines ?

Comment: Why are you calling iter and why not just iterate over the instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is because you are indexing the ingredient not the tuple, `ingredient[self.index]` should be `self.ingredient_list[self.index]`.

You could  simplify your code to behave like yours but work by making *args* *iterable* so you can pass the strings as you were without needing to put them in a list etc..:

```
class Vegan:
    NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT = ['egg', 'milk', 'honey', 'butter']

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.ingredient_iter = iter(args)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        ingredient = next(self.ingredient_iter)
        if ingredient in Vegan.NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT:
            return '{} is a vegan ingredient'.format(ingredient)
        return '{} is NOT a vegan ingredient'.format(ingredient)


iterable = Vegan('tomato', 'banana', 'asd', 'egg', 'tomato')

for ele in iterable:
    print(ele)
```

Output:

```
In [2]: iterable = Vegan('tomato', 'banana', 'asd', 'egg', 'tomato')

In [3]: for ele in iterable:
   ...:         print(ele)
   ...:     
tomato is NOT a vegan ingredient
banana is NOT a vegan ingredient
asd is NOT a vegan ingredient
egg is a vegan ingredient
tomato is NOT a vegan ingredient
```

You raise a Stopiteration in your own code but calling `next(iterable)` will do the same so, the point of making an object iterable is you can iterate directly over it so no need for a try/except. Also *I'm passing args, which should be a list* is incorrect, args is a tuple.

Also if you have a lot of ingredients to check making `NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT` a set would be more efficient:

```
NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT = {'egg', 'milk', 'honey', 'butter'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution to your problem:

```
class Vegan:

    NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT = ['egg', 'milk', 'honey', 'butter']

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.ingredient_list = (args)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index >= len(self.ingredient_list):
            raise StopIteration

        ingredient = self.ingredient_list[self.index]
        self.index += 1

        if ingredient in Vegan.NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT:
            return ('{} is a vegan ingredient'.format(ingredient))
        else:
            return ('{} is NOT a vegan ingredient'.format(ingredient))

iterable = Vegan('tomato', 'banana', 'asd', 'egg', 'tomato')
iterator = iter(iterable)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(iterator))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

In any case, I think this problem could be solved in 1 or 2 lines instead of using `__iter__` and `__next__` methods like this

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your class is that you're looping through the elements in your `__next__()` method. Here is a solution using your code:

```
class Vegan:

    NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT = ['egg', 'milk', 'honey', 'butter']

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.ingredient_list = args
        self.index = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == len(self.ingredient_list) - 1:  # index is incremented
            raise StopIteration
        self.index += 1
        if self.ingredient_list[self.index] in Vegan.NONE_VEGAN_INGREDIENT:
            return ('{} is a vegan ingredient'.format(self.ingredient_list[self.index]))
        else:
            return ('{} is NOT a vegan ingredient'.format(self.ingredient_list[self.index]))

iterable = Vegan('tomato', 'banana', 'asd', 'egg', 'tomato')
iterator = iter(iterable)
while True:
    try:
        print(next(iterator))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

All I did was change the check for index out of bounds to `len() - 1` and removed the for loop. This works, producing the output I assume you were going for:

```
tomato is NOT a vegan ingredient
banana is NOT a vegan ingredient
asd is NOT a vegan ingredient
egg is a vegan ingredient
tomato is NOT a vegan ingredient
```

edit: fixed issue with if statement

Comment: You forgot to mention one fix you made that caused the odd behavior with the single letters: change `.format(ingredient[self.index])` to `.format(self.ingredient_list[self.index])`.

Comment: asd is not included in the vegan_ingredients list, but I got your point. Fixed the code.